# Transition to another route on successful async redux action

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-router, redux

I have a pretty simple set of react components:

- `container` that hooks into [redux](http://rackt.github.io/redux/) and handles the actions, store subscriptions, etc
- `list` which displays a list of my items
- `new` which is a form to add a new item to the list

I have some [react-router](https://github.com/rackt/react-router) routes as follows:

```
<Route name='products' path='products' handler={ProductsContainer}>
  <Route name='productNew' path='new' handler={ProductNew} />
  <DefaultRoute handler={ProductsList} />
</Route>
```

so that either the `list` or the `form` are shown but not both.

What I'd like to do is to have the application re-route back to the list once a new item has been successfully added.

My solution so far is to have a `.then()` after the async `dispatch`:

```
dispatch(actions.addProduct(product)
  .then(this.transitionTo('products'))
)
```

Is this the correct way to do this or should I fire another action somehow to trigger the route change?

Comment: Have you take a look at https://github.com/acdlite/redux-react-router ?
It stores router store in redux so you are able to trigger route changes as redux actions.

Comment: I've had a look at `redux-react-router` and this will require a large refactor so may have to wait. If I come up with a solution in the meantime I'll post an answer

Comment: @Dmitry the question then is where you trigger from once props (e.g. a isAuthenticated flag) are updated. componentWillReceiveProps?

Answer (score 29, accepted):

If you don't want to use a more complete solution like [Redux Router](https://github.com/acdlite/redux-react-router), you can use [Redux History Transitions](https://github.com/johanneslumpe/redux-history-transitions) which lets you write code like this:

```
export function login() {
  return {
    type: LOGGED_IN,
    payload: {
      userId: 123
    }
    meta: {
      transition: (state, action) => ({
        path: `/logged-in/${action.payload.userId}`,
        query: {
          some: 'queryParam'
        },
        state: {
          some: 'state'
        }
      })
    }
  };
}
```

This is similar to [what you suggested](https://stackoverflow.com/a/32648701/458193) but a tiny bit more sophisticated. It still uses the same [history](https://github.com/rackt/history) library under the hood so it's compatible with React Router.

Comment: It needs a comma after `payload: { userId: 123}`

Answer (score 26):

I ended up creating a super simple middleware that roughtly looks like that:

```
import history from "../routes/history";

export default store => next => action => {

    if ( ! action.redirect ) return next(action);

    history.replaceState(null, action.redirect);
}
```

So from there you just need to make sure that your `successful` actions have a `redirect` property. Also note, this middleware does not trigger `next()`. This is on purpose as a route transition should be the end of the action chain.

Comment: Doesn't work with thunk middleware in place? If you move from 'LOGIN_STARTED' to 'LOGIN_SUCCESSFUL' and don't call next nothing will happen.

Comment: This is the smallest working solution. Thanks for sharing.

Comment: What is `../routes/history` here?

Comment: What is ../router/history here? And does this still work?

Answer (score 20):

For those that are using a middleware API layer to abstract their usage of something like [isomorphic-fetch](https://github.com/matthew-andrews/isomorphic-fetch), and also happen to be using [redux-thunk](http://feature/dispatch-async-actions), you can simply chain off your `dispatch` Promise inside of your actions, like so:

```
import { push } from 'react-router-redux';
const USER_ID = // imported from JWT;

function fetchUser(primaryKey, opts) {
    // this prepares object for the API middleware
}

// this can be called from your container
export function updateUser(payload, redirectUrl) {
    var opts = {
        method: 'PUT',
        headers: {
            'Content-Type': 'application/json'
        },
        body: JSON.stringify(payload)
    };
    return (dispatch) => {
        return dispatch(fetchUser(USER_ID, opts))
            .then((action) => {
                if (action.type === ActionTypes.USER_SUCCESS) {
                    dispatch(push(redirectUrl));
                }
            });
    };
}
```

This reduces the need for adding libraries into your code as suggested [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/32922381/728013), and also nicely co-locates your actions with their redirects as done in [redux-history-transitions](https://github.com/johanneslumpe/redux-history-transitions).

Here is what my store looks like:

```
import { createStore, applyMiddleware } from 'redux';
import rootReducer from '../reducers';
import thunk from 'redux-thunk';
import api from '../middleware/api';
import { routerMiddleware } from 'react-router-redux';

export default function configureStore(initialState, browserHistory) {
    const store = createStore(
        rootReducer,
        initialState,
        applyMiddleware(thunk, api, routerMiddleware(browserHistory))
    );

    return store;
}
```

Comment: does that really works... cuz its aint working for me

Comment: Not working in the sense url get redirected but my content in the page does not change.. It displays the same page even when url is changed..

Comment: are you using a router? which router and what add-ons? This code is written with React-Router and React-Router-Redux in mind

Comment: This worked for me, but you must have the `routerMiddleware` in included in your store https://github.com/reactjs/react-router-redux#what-if-i-want-to-issue-navigation-events-via-redux-actions

Comment: For those like me wondering where function `push` is coming from: `import { push } from 'react-router-redux'`

Answer (score 0):

I know I am little late in the party as react-navigation is already included in the react-native documentation, but still it can be useful for the user who have used/using Navigator api in their apps.
what I tried is little hackish, I am saving navigator instance in object as soon as renderScene happens-

```
renderScene(route, navigator) {
      const Component = Routes[route.Name]
      api.updateNavigator(navigator); //will allow us to access navigator anywhere within the app
      return <Component route={route} navigator={navigator} data={route.data}/>

}
```

my api file is something lke this

```
'use strict';

//this file includes all my global functions
import React, {Component} from 'react';
import {Linking, Alert, NetInfo, Platform} from 'react-native';
var api = {
    navigator,
    isAndroid(){
        return (Platform.OS === 'android');
    },
    updateNavigator(_navigator){
      if(_navigator)
          this.navigator = _navigator;
    },
}

module.exports = api;
```

now in your actions you can simply call

> api.navigator.push({Name:'routeName',
>   data:WHATEVER_YOU_WANTED_TO_PASS)

you just need to import your api from the module.

Answer (score 0):

If you're using [react-redux](https://github.com/reduxjs/react-redux) and [react-router](https://github.com/ReactTraining/react-router), then I think [this link](https://serverless-stack.com/chapters/redirect-on-login-and-logout.html) provides a great solution.

Here's the steps I used:

- Pass in a react-router `history` prop to your component, either by rendering your component inside a react-router `<Route/>` component or by creating a Higher Order Component using `withRouter`.
- Next, create the route you want to redirect to (I called mine `to`).
- Third, call your redux action with both `history` and `to`.
- Finally, when you want to redirect (e.g., when your redux action resolves), call `history.push(to)`.